# dispatch.earliest_time in Splunk savedsearch.conf

Tags: splunk

I am new to splunk, and trying to understand what’s the difference between dispatch.earliest_time = "-15m@m" and dispatch.earliest_time = "-15m”. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no practical difference. Both begin the search 15 minutes before the current time.  The `@m` portion rounds off the start time to beginning of the minute, but is not necessary since the search scheduler uses minute resolution.